# Rebuild rpm under centos

Tags: mysql, centos, rpm

i need to install MySQL 4.1 under a Centos web server(My centos release is 6.4, x86_64),
can anyone please **help me** with rebuilding so many dependencies?
I use **rpmrebuild** command and **gcc, gcc-c++** are already installed.
[Here](http://download.softagency.net/MySQL/Downloads/MySQL-4.1/) is the rpm list which i need.

**EDIT** 
I added Freebsd as an alternative, can anyone please suggest a port collection for MySQL 4.1 please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please just give an idea instead of downvoting?

Comment: This needs more background. Why don't you use the MySQL packages that come with CentOS?

Comment: @freiheit Hi, the company i started uses mysql 4.1 on freebsd, they want to have a bacup cluster to the live system so they asked me to install MySQL 4.1.. I m free i f i use Linux, freebsd, mac or anything, i will try to install on freebsd for the moment

Answer (score 1):

First off: mysql 4.1 is *ancient*. Instead of investing time in rebuilding it, invest time in upgrading to 5.0, 5.1 and then 5.5.

Now for the rebuild, this is how I generally do this, as non-root user:

```
$ sudo yum install yum-utils
$ echo '%_topdir %(echo $HOME)/rpmbuild' > ~/.rpmmacros
$ sudo yum-builddep mysql
$ rpm -i MySQL-4.1.22-0.src.rpm
$ rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/mysql.spec
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, you are right about upgrading but they rejected that sugeestion. Thay say that their code has run too slow on MySQL 5 strangely. I will try to solve this situation for them.